# wave phase adjustment between several signals

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Can anyone help me on this?

I have a file with 8 wave signals that belong to the same wave gauge S1:

[image]

The idea is to adjust the phase of the signals so that they start with the same wave phase and height.

If I do this manually (as I did in the figure) I have to shift each signal in time until I find a proper overlap for the 8 signals.

Is there any function/routine available for this purpose?

Many thanks!

I would like to use Matlab. The plot was made in Tecplot.

The idea is to overlap the signals and then do the average wave of the 8 signals.

Here is the file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bc9imi5frhakgxz/time_phases1.csv

Comment: You haven't specified what language/environment you are using - I'm guessing it's MATLAB ?

Comment: Perhaps use cross-correlation between one signal that will serve as the reference with the other 7 signals as being queries.  You can then determine the best phase shift and adjust your signal from there.  Can you tell us what language you are using?  The figure you generated above was not generated using MATLAB.

Comment: Also, please provide a way for us to download your data.  It would be impossible for us to test out our theories if we don't have the data that you are using to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

to align the signals you can use a zero crossing method, basically you find the zero crossings point of each signal then shift the signals until the zero crossing position is the same.
if you have a noisy signal, pass the signals through a low pass filter first,
and if you have a dc component pass the signals through a high pass filter.

for similar height you can factor the waveform peak or the rms-which will be more accurate,
example:  divide factor = rms1/rms2 and then multiply factor by signal 2.